# How to determine a winner in Hangman Game?

Tags: java, android

I have created a Hangman game in Android Studio. It is working as it should be when drawing down the letters to form the words etc. and the number of tries remaining.

i am stuck on determining when the player has won in the logic to prompt an AlertDialog box and start a new game. Appreciate if some light can be shed on how i can do this?

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.AlertDialogLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.ImageSwitcher;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;

import java.util.Random;

public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//To reference the components
ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher;
TextView textView;
TextView textViewScore;
Button btn [] = new Button[26];

AlertDialog helpAlert;

//Images for the hangman
int img [] = {R.drawable.img0,
        R.drawable.img1,
        R.drawable.img2,
        R.drawable.img3,
        R.drawable.img4,
        R.drawable.img5,
        R.drawable.img6,
        R.drawable.img7,
        R.drawable.img8};

//Variables
String strSecret = "", strGuess="", strText="";

String strWords[] = {"APPLE", "ORANGE","BANANA"};

int intError = 0; //Error made by player

int livesRemaining = 8; //Lives remaining by player

Random random = new Random(); //Random generator


//To create help icon at top right
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

//To create help icon at top right
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        //case android.R.id.home:
           // NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            //return true;
        case R.id.action_help:
            showHelp();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    //Retrieve the reference
    imageSwitcher = findViewById(R.id.imageSwitcher);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textViewScore = findViewById(R.id.textViewScore);
    textViewScore.setText(String.valueOf(livesRemaining));
    setupImageSwitcher();
    setup26Buttons();
    getSecretWord();

}


private void setup26Buttons() {

    GridLayout g = findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);


    //to create 26 buttons
    for(int i = 0; i<btn.length; i++) {

        btn[i] =new Button(this, null, R.attr.buttonStyleSmall); //Buttonsytlesmall so that it fits the screen
        btn[i].setText(""+(char)('A'+i)); //need to set back to char, as +i will set it back to integer. "" to set this to a String so it is sync to setText
        btn[i].setTag(""+(char)('A'+i));
        btn[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                strGuess += v.getTag(); //Get letter that the player guessed and keep adding on to strGuess
                v.setEnabled(false); //disable pressed button since the player already press
                v.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.black);

                //Check for error guess. If the letter is not inside the strSecret, it will return less than 0
                if (strSecret.indexOf(v.getTag().toString())<0){

                    intError++; //your error is added
                    int livesRemaining = 8;
                    livesRemaining -= intError; // Countdown based on errors recorded
                    textViewScore.setText(String.valueOf(livesRemaining));
                    imageSwitcher.setImageResource(img[intError]); //set the img no. to follow the error
                }

                //Display all correct guesses
                strText = ""; //reset the display

                for (int i = 0 ; i<strSecret.length();i++){

                    char ch = strSecret.charAt(i); // get each character from strSecret

                    //To check if this letter can be found in strGuess
                    if(strGuess.indexOf(ch)>=0){
                        //found
                        strText += ch;

                    }

                    else{

                        //Not found
                        strText += "-";
                    }

                }

                textView.setText(strText);

            }

        });



        g.addView(btn[i]);

    }

}

private void getSecretWord() {

    int index = random.nextInt(strWords.length);
    strSecret = strWords[index];

    for(int i=0; i<strSecret.length(); i++) {

        strText += "-"; //to create multiple - for the unknown word

    }

    textView.setText(strText);


}

private void setupImageSwitcher() {

    //https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_imageswitcher.htm
    imageSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {

        @Override
        public View makeView() {

            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img0);

            return imageView;
        }
    });

    Animation aniOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

    Animation aniIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);

    imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(aniOut);

    imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(aniIn);
}

//show help information
public void showHelp(){
    AlertDialog.Builder helpBuild = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    helpBuild.setTitle("Help");
    helpBuild.setMessage("Whisper the password (Hangman's favourite fruit) to save Batman\n\n"
            + "You only have 8 tries!");
    helpBuild.setPositiveButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    helpAlert.dismiss();
                }});
    helpAlert = helpBuild.create();
    helpBuild.show();
}
```

}

Comment: Well from the normal Hangman game, the player has won when he has guessed the correct word. So you need to check after every input the user gives, if the word is complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a boolean flag in your `onClickListener`s `onClick` method. Example code:

```
// Display all correct guesses
String strText = ""; // reset the display
boolean allFound = true;

for (int i = 0; i < strSecret.length(); i++)
{
    char ch = strSecret.charAt(i); // get each character from strSecret

    // To check if this letter can be found in strGuess
    if (strGuess.indexOf(ch) >= 0)
    {
        // found
        strText += ch;
    }
    else
    {
        // Not found
        strText += "-";
        allFound = false;
    }

}

if(allFound)
{
    // Word was guessed correctly
    [...]
}
```

`allFound` is a boolean flag that is defaulting to true. Should you not find one guessed character you set it to false. After looping through the full word you check if it is still true, meaning that no character was not found which in turn means every character was found.

In that case you can be sure your word was guessed correctly and can act accordingly.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks Ben. such a simple solution and i just couldnt see it. Many Thanks! works like a charm.